# error when update_rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I try to update gem I gave this:

- 4 bug fixes:

  - Use Psych API to emit more compatible YAML
  - Download and write inside `gem fetch` directly. Fixes #289
  - Honor sysconfdir on 1.8. Fixes #291
  - Search everywhere for a spec for `gem spec`. Fixes #288
  - Fix Gem.all_load_path. Fixes #171

Help me fix it please :D

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be valid output from updating RubyGems. Did you run this command?

```
gem update --system
```

If so, and you saw that output, you should be able to run this and get the version number.

```
gem --version
```

It should be something along the lines of `1.8.17`, which is the latest version.

Comment: I remove and install rubygems 1.8.10 . It 's ok
for 1.8.17 it have that error, maybe because I am using ruby 1.9.2
Thank for your reply

Comment: @Peter_175 glad to hear it's working for you, then. If I answered your question, be sure to mark my response as your solution.